# Snackbar duration does not work properly on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-design-library

I have simple method to display Snackbar from `android.support.design.widget.Snackbar`. I want to hide it after 3 seconds, so I wrote:

```
fun showSnackbar(text: CharSequence, view:View): Snackbar {
    val snackbar = Snackbar
        .make(view, text, 3000)

    snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(view.context, R.color.accent_color))
    snackbar.show()
    return snackbar
}
```

Code works perfectly on emulator and on some devices. But when I run same code on Samsung and Xiaomi (with MIUI, Android one devices dont have that problem) it hides almost immediatly without any reasons.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why this is happening, but not how to fix yet.

```
/**
 * Returns true if we should animate the Snackbar view in/out.
 */
private boolean shouldAnimate() {
    return !mAccessibilityManager.isEnabled();
}
```

That is called by Snackbar class and is false on working devices, and true on devices not working. Does anyone know about this?

So after i disabled lastpass in my system settings, accessibility the snackbar now animates as it should. That is crazy how that works. Nova launcher has the same affect. I guess any service in accessibility that is enabled will cause the snackbar animation to not work.